# Segfault for a memcpy overlap during mmap

Tags: c

I'm experiencing a mmap problem that I can't seem to solve. Here is the setup: I allocate a huge multidimensional array into memory with malloc, I fill it with my values, and then I want to save it in a file. The array contains 3200000000 bytes. The machine is a 64-bit one and has enough memory to do so.

```
Linux 2.6.32-27-server #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 2 02:05:21 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The file creation with mmap works just fine, I get the ptrFile pointer.
When I memcpy my array into that ptrFile pointer, the program crashes with a segfault.

After a few debugging, I see that the two buffers overlap. The data array begins at address 0x7FEC47FFF010 and the pointer returned by mmap is 0x7FEA2543E000. I tried memmove to solve this, but the result is the same. If I restrict the size copied to the file to 1000 bytes, it works just fine.

How come the two allocated pointer overlap?

Thanks a lot!

-- J

Comment: You are most probably writing more memory than you ever allocated, this results in overlapping buffers(partially overlapping objects), and an UB.

Comment: Try posting /proc/$pid/maps (so we can see the mapped file is long enough)

Comment: There's probably a integer overflow somewhere in your code. It happens quite easily if you don't qualify all constants with `ULL` and mix int variable liberally. IKt's important to use `size_t` or `uintptr_t` when handling big memory objects.

Answer (score 2):

Those memory regions do *not* overlap (as long as your `mmap` block is the size you say it is).  `0x7FEC47FFF010` - `0x7FEA2543E000` = `9,172,684,816`, which is much larger than the size of `3,200,000,000` that you have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

mmap() cannot extend the file. Before copying the data, you first have to enlarge file to the proper size, using, for example, ftruncate. Though using mmap to just copy data to a file is overkill, just using write(2) is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a `mmap`? If the only thing you want to make is to save your memory block, then a simple `write` or `fwrite` of the malloc'ed area will suffice. You only have to be sure that they handle 64 bit sizes.

Comment: They take `size_t`, so you can pass the size of any object, and thus the size of your giant array (assuming you were able to allocate it in the first place).